# Why can't I edit files using nano

Tags: server, mount, sudo, fstab, nano

I'm trying to update the file `/etc/fstab/` so I can automatically mount my drive on startup.

I used the `sudo mount -a` command to check for any errors and I realised I have a typo in the file. I raced back to the file to update it as obviously I don't want anything to restart yet I can't see any text, just the number of lines there are in the file? I used the command `sudo nano -w /etc/fstab`.

Why is this? I would like to fix the file asap but I cannot access it...

[image]

Comment: What happens if you don't use the -w switch?

Comment: You are ding something wrong, or the file doesn't exist. It works for me.

Comment: @Pilot6 The file does exist and that's the only command I put in and nothing shows up?

Comment: Maybe the file has been locked. From [the manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html): "Note that it is a bad practice to use `mount -a` for _fstab_ checking. The recommended solution is `findmnt --verify`."

Comment: Try from a virtual console: log in to one using Ctrl+Alt+F4 (or higher), and hopefully, the contents of your file will be displayed there. Anyway, if you did not mess up other lines, your error will not necessarily lead to your system becoming unbootable.